# Help with Fitch formal proof?

Tags: logic, proof, fitch

I'm having trouble solving this formal proof in Fitch. I've put together most of it, but I think I need to use disjunction elim(?) at some point and am having trouble doing that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So very close.

You have all the pieces for this, but you wandered off the path along the way.

You knew to seek to derive `Small(b)` under the assumption of `Small(c)`.   You immediately derived `Small(d) v Small(e)` and *correctly* decided to eliminate this disjunction... then apparently *forgot* where you wanted to go.

**Always keep an eye on the destination**.

The first case of `Small(d)` should have derived `Small(b)` by contradiction elimination .

The second case of `Small(e)` must aim for the same; and here what you needed to do was nest a second disjunction elimination.   The disjunction to eliminate is the first premise, `Small(b) v Cube(b)` -- the first case is trivial, and the second case I am sure that you can do, so...

```
|  Small(b) v Cube(b)              P
|  Small(c) > Small(d) v Small(e)  P
|  Small(d) > ~Small(c)            P
|_ Cube(b) > ~Small(e)             P
|  |_ Small(c)                     A
|  |  Small(d) v Small(e)          >E   
|  |  |_ Small(d)                  A
|  |  |  ~Small(c)                 >E   
|  |  |  #                         #I     <- you had it up to here
|  |  |  Small(b)                  #E     <- derive this instead
|  |  +
|  |  |_ Small(e)                  A
|  |  |  Small(b) v Cube(b)        R      <- the first premise
|  |  |  |_ Small(b)               A                  
|  |  |  |  Small(b)               R
|  |  |  +
|  |  |  |_ Cube(b)                A
|  |  |  |  :                      :
|  |  |  |  Small(b)               .
|  |  |  Small(b)                  vE
|  |  Small(b)                     vE
|  Small(c) > Small(b)             >I
```